# SQL: identify if there are multiples (not duplicates) in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am currently struggling in identifying a possibility to identify certain patterns in my data using SSMS.
I wish to identify rows that contain multiples (x*2, x*3, or x*4) of an entry within the same column.

I really have no clue on how to even start my "where" statement right now.

```
SELECT  [numbers], [product_ID]
FROM [db].[dbo].[tablename]
WHERE [numbers] = numbers*2
```

My problem is that with the code above I can obviously only identify zeros.

Google only helps me out with finding duplicates but I can't find a way to identify multiples of a value...

My desired result would be a table that only contains numbers (linked to product_IDs) that are multiples of each other

Anyone can help me out here?

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. `[numbers] = numbers*2` will never be true unless `numbers` has the value `0` (as `0*2 = 0`).

Answer (score 1):

If a column contains multiples, then all are multiples of the smallest non-zero value.  Let me assume the values are positive or zero for this purpose.

So, you can determine if this is the case using window functions and modulo arithmetic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when number > 0 then number end) over () as min_number
      from t
     ) t
where number % min_number = 0 or min_number = 1;
```

If you want to know if *all* numbers meet this criteria, use aggregation:

```
select (case when min(number % min_number) = 0 then 'all multiples' else 'oops' end)
from (select t.*,
             min(case when number > 0 then number end) over () as min_number
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

> My desired result would be a table that only contains numbers (linked to product_IDs) that are multiples of each other

You'll need to test all pairs of rows, which means a CROSS JOIN.

Something like this:

```
with q as
(
SELECT  [numbers], 
        [product_ID], 
        cast(a.numbers as float) / coalesce(b.numbers, null) ratio
FROM [tablename] a
CROSS JOIN [tablename] b
)
select *
from q
where ratio = cast(ratio as bigint)
and ratio > 1
```